# Get the admin's system.xml file data on front-end block file

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, adminhtml, system.xml, scopeinterface

I have added input box in admin's system.xml along with other fields as below:

```
<field id="mapping" translate="label comment tooltip" sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
  <label>Exclude Days</label>
    <frontend_model>VENDOR\DeliveryCountdown\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\excludeDays</frontend_model>
       <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
         <comment>
           <![CDATA[Add bank holidays that are not included in delivery / cut off times.]]>
          </comment>
            <tooltip>Delivery and cuttoff not include these days.</tooltip>
</field>
```

This display in admin as:

[image]

I can add many input boxes by clicking **ADD** button. Below is code to receive input dates of above form:

> $offDays =
>   $this->scopeConfig->getValue('deliverycountdown/general/mapping',
>   \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

But output is as below:

> a:3:{s:17:"_1509434435073_73";
>
> a:2:{s:6:"field1";s:4:"AAAA";s:6:"field2";s:10:"2017-11-01";}s:18:"_1509434856288_288";
>
> a:2:{s:6:"field1";s:4:"BBBB";s:6:"field2";s:10:"2017-11-03";}s:18:"_1509434861359_359";
>   a:2:{s:6:"field1";s:4:"CCCC";s:6:"field2";s:10:"2017-11-06";} }

It would great help to get dates from this file (i think JSON).

Or guide me another way if thats possible to add fields in admin and get at front-end block file.

Answer (score 2):

For grids controls in system configuration using backend model

`<backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>`

which serialize array data on save and unserialize before passing to view model.

You need to use `\Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface::unserialize` (for test you can use [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)) to get original field value with serialized backend model.

Note, that in Magento 2.2 `json` serializer using as default serializer, so if you will work with low level `unserialize` then you module will throw exception in 2.2.

---

```
$offDays = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('deliverycountdown/general/mapping', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
print_r(unserialize($offDays));
```

Comment: Where to add this : \Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface::unserialize

Comment: add Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface as argument in constructor and use $this->serializer->unserialize($offDayas);

Comment: My construct in magento 2.1.9 as below==== 

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
  \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date    // For date and time functions
    ) {
        $this->date = $date;
  $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct(
            $context
        );
    }

===========  Please guide

Comment: add ` \Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface $serializer` after `$date` argument and `$this->serializer = $serializer;` in constructor body

Comment: I had tried the same in my module but PHPSTORM highlight error as : Serialize namespace not defined. Site dont load in browser

Comment: looks like this package not exist in `2.1`. In this case try to use `unserialize` function

Answer (score 0):

I done it with following string functions and its working fine.

```
    $offDaysString='a:9:{s:17:"_1509434435073_73";
a:2:{s:6:"field1";s:4:"AAAA";s:6:"field2";s:10:"2017-11-01";}s:18:"_1509434856288_288";
a:2:{s:6:"field1";s:4:"BBBB";s:6:"field2";s:10:"2017-11-03";}s:18:"_1509434861359_359";
a:2:{s:6:"field1";s:4:"CCCC";s:6:"field2";s:10:"2017-11-06";}s:18:"_1509435862561_561";
a:2:{s:6:"field1";s:5:"DDDDD";s:6:"field2";s:10:"2017-11-09";}s:18:"_1509435867703_703";
a:2:{s:6:"field1";s:12:"EEEEEEEEEEEE";s:6:"field2";s:10:"2017-11-12";}s:17:"_1509435870047_47";
a:2:{s:6:"field1";s:12:"FFFFFFFFFFFF";s:6:"field2";s:10:"2017-11-14";}s:18:"_1509435872376_376";
a:2:{s:6:"field1";s:14:"GGGGGGGGGGGGGG";s:6:"field2";s:10:"2017-11-16";}s:18:"_1509435874879_879";
a:2:{s:6:"field1";s:12:"HHHHHHHHHHHH";s:6:"field2";s:10:"2017-11-17";}s:18:"_1509435877463_463";
a:2:{s:6:"field1";s:13:"IIIIIIIIIIIII";s:6:"field2";s:10:"2017-11-20";}}' ; 


        $needle = 's:10:"';
        $count = substr_count($offDaysString, $needle);

        $position = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

            $pos = strpos($offDaysString, $needle, $position);
            $position = $pos + 6;// length of this - s:10:
            $startPoint[] = $position;
            $Offdates[] = substr($offDaysString, $startPoint[$i], 10); // 10 = 2017-11-20

        }

        print_r($Offdates);
```

> For me, above code working fine and i put it in function in block file
>   and called in template file displayed dates.

If anyone get a better to receive values on front-end block then post answer. Thanks

Comment: you must not use parsing of serialized values, see my answer